# find subdocument by id inside a array field of nested object

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

If I have a document like this:

```
{
   "_id": ObjectId("54e6774a73a7edfefdb9e2bc"),
   "information":"",
   "__v":0,
   "goalieRoster":{
      "locked":[

      ],
      "approved":[
         {
            "_id": ObjectId("548d49bad972605bf2d1f55a"), // find by this
         }
      ],
      "signedUp":[
         {
            "_id": ObjectId("548d49bad972605bf2d1f55a"),
         }
      ],
      "maxSize":2
   },
   "skaterRoster":{
      "locked":[

      ],
      "approved":[

      ],
      "signedUp":[

      ],
      "maxSize":26
   },
   "date":{
      "updated":"2015-02-20T02:56:42.258Z",
      "skate":""
   }
}
```

How would I grab the whole subdocument inside `approved` by the subdocument's id?
I think I am close, as the following query almost does what I want.

```
db.roster.find(
        {
            "goalieRoster.approved._id": ObjectId("548d54e9576ddacc20f3a88e")
        },
        {
            "goalieRoster.approved": 1
        }
);
```

It returns the parent document and the than the matching subdocument inside `approved` array nested inside `goalieRoster` like so

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54e6774a73a7edfefdb9e2bc"),
    "goalieRoster" : {
        "approved" : [
            {
                "_id" : ObjectId("548d54e9576ddacc20f3a88e"),
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The problem is all i want is the subdocument inside `approved`. Also, is it possible to drop the `goalieRoster` to just `approved` and have it look inside both the approved array in `goalieRoster` and `skaterRoster`?

**Edit: The result I was looking for is this**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("548d54e9576ddacc20f3a88e"),
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

What you want is projection with the [**`$`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/projection/positional/#proj._S_) operator.

```js
db.test.find({"goalieRoster.approved._id": ObjectId("548d49bad972605bf2d1f55a")},
    {"goalieRoster.approved.$": true}
)
```

**Result**

```js
{
    "_id" : "54e6774a73a7edfefdb9e2bc", 
    "goalieRoster" : { "approved" : [ { "_id" : "548d54e9576ddacc20f3a88e" } ] }
}
```